# Code to change an xml tag if a certain value exists

Tags: xml, tag

This code changes the tag value from false to true **if** the false tag value exists (which is what I want)

But **if** the tag value in the xml is true this as it is changes all the tags in the xml to true. What edit would need to be made to make the change only if the actual tag value exists and it is false?

```
#!/bin/bash
linenumber=$(grep -n '<example>false</example>' test.xml | awk -F':' '{ print $1 }')
sed -i.old'' ${linenumber}s/false/true/ test.xml
```

Comment: Hopefully that is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly if `linenumber` is empty (because `grep` finds no match) then your command becomes the globally addressed `s/false/true/`.

Instead of trying to extract a line number using a regex match, you can just address your sed command using a regex match directly ex. `sed '\#<example>false</example>#s/false/true/'`.

However line-based tools like sed and grep are really the wrong approach for structured text - you should consider using a proper XML tool such as `xmlstarlet` instead.